# How to efficiently remove a query string by Key from a Url?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url, query-string

How to remove a query string by Key from a Url?

I have the below method which works fine but just wondering is there any better/shorter way? or a built-in .NET method which can do it more efficiently?

```
 public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
        {
            var indexOfQuestionMark = url.IndexOf("?");
            if (indexOfQuestionMark == -1)
            {
                return url;
            }

            var result = url.Substring(0, indexOfQuestionMark);
            var queryStrings = url.Substring(indexOfQuestionMark + 1);
            var queryStringParts = queryStrings.Split(new [] {'&'});
            var isFirstAdded = false;

            for (int index = 0; index <queryStringParts.Length; index++)
            {
                var keyValue = queryStringParts[index].Split(new char[] { '=' });
                if (keyValue[0] == key)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!isFirstAdded)
                {
                    result += "?";
                    isFirstAdded = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result += "&";
                }

                result += queryStringParts[index];
            }

            return result;
        }
```

For example I can call it like:

```
  Console.WriteLine(RemoveQueryStringByKey(@"http://www.domain.com/uk_pa/PostDetail.aspx?hello=hi&xpid=4578", "xpid"));
```

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Querystring - Find, replace, add, update values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163956/url-querystring-find-replace-add-update-values)

Comment: Tag: 'reinventing-the-wheel' [`System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`]

Comment: neither has the full solution nor answers the question asked.

Comment: Could you give an example of input and output?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This works well:

```
public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
{                   
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    // this gets all the query string key value pairs as a collection
    var newQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

    // this removes the key if exists
    newQueryString.Remove(key);

    // this gets the page path from root without QueryString
    string pagePathWithoutQueryString = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

    return newQueryString.Count > 0
        ? String.Format("{0}?{1}", pagePathWithoutQueryString, newQueryString)
        : pagePathWithoutQueryString;
}
```

an example:

```
RemoveQueryStringByKey("https://www.google.co.uk/search?#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cookie", "q");
```

and returns:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/search?#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab
```

Comment: string doesnt contain defination for FormatWith method

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using FormatWith? That's not available in .NET 4.0

Comment: This works if the url has protocol. The Uri constructor throws if it's missing.
i.e.
new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com") - works
but new Uri("stackoverflow.com") does not.

Comment: Those of you mentioning the invalid format issue, you are more than likely already dealing with a URI perhaps. You can simply change this method to accept the Uri instead of the string url. Then you simply delete the line creating one from the string.

Comment: This answer missed Uri.Fragment (the hash #xxx) handling. So the URL like "https://www.google.co.uk/search?#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cookie#xxx" will losethe "#xxx" after processing. So the returned value should add uri.Fragment

Answer (score 11):

```
    var queryString = "hello=hi&xpid=4578";
    var qs = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    qs.Remove("xpid");
    var newQuerystring = qs.ToString();
```

This still works in .NET 5.

Comment: This solution is cool because the Remove() method actually works.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a rather old question, but everything I read felt a bit complicated.

```
public Uri GetUriWithoutQueryParam( Uri originalUri, string paramKey ) {
  NameValueCollection newQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( originalUri.Query );
  newQuery.Remove( paramKey );
  return new UriBuilder( originalUri ) { Query = newQuery.ToString() }.Uri;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a useful class called [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) in the System namespace. We can use it along with a couple of extension methods to do the following:

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2");
u = u.DropQueryItem("key1");
```

Or like this:

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2");
UriBuilder b = new UriBuilder(u);
b.RemoveQueryItem("key1");
u = b.Uri;
```

The extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static Uri DropQueryItem(this Uri u, string key)
    {
        UriBuilder b = new UriBuilder(u);
        b.RemoveQueryItem(key);
        return b.Uri;
    }
}
public static class UriBuilderExtensions
{
    private static string _ParseQueryPattern = @"(?<key>[^&=]+)={0,1}(?<value>[^&]*)";
    private static Regex _ParseQueryRegex = null;

    private static Regex ParseQueryRegex
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ParseQueryRegex == null)
            {
                _ParseQueryRegex = new Regex(_ParseQueryPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            }
            return _ParseQueryRegex;

        }
    }

    public static void SetQueryItem(this UriBuilder b, string key, string value)
    {
        NameValueCollection parms = ParseQueryString(b.Query);
        parms[key] = value;
        b.Query = RenderQuery(parms);
    }

    public static void RemoveQueryItem(this UriBuilder b, string key)
    {
        NameValueCollection parms = ParseQueryString(b.Query);
        parms.Remove(key);
        b.Query = RenderQuery(parms);
    }       
    private static string RenderQuery(NameValueCollection parms)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<parms.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = parms.Keys[i];
            sb.Append(key + "=" + parms[key]);
            if (i < parms.Count - 1)
            {
                sb.Append("&");
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(string query, bool caseSensitive = true)
    {
        NameValueCollection pairs = new NameValueCollection(caseSensitive ? StringComparer.Ordinal : StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        string q = query.Trim().TrimStart(new char[] {'?'});
        MatchCollection matches = ParseQueryRegex.Matches(q);

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            string key = m.Groups["key"].Value;
            string value = m.Groups["value"].Value;
            if (pairs[key] != null)
            {
                pairs[key] = pairs[key] + "," + value;
            }
            else
            {
                pairs[key] = value;
            }

        }

        return pairs;

    }

}
```

Comment: UriBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveQueryItem' and no accessible extension method 'RemoveQueryItem' accepting a first argument of type 'UriBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) on 4.6 dotnet version

Comment: @TommyHolman Sorrry about that. It turns out RemoveQueryItem was my own extension method on UriBuilder.  I've updated my answer to include it.

Answer (score 3):

We can also do it using regex

```
string queryString = "Default.aspx?Agent=10&Language=2"; //Request.QueryString.ToString();
string parameterToRemove="Language";   //parameter which we want to remove
string regex=string.Format("(&{0}=[^&\s]+|(?<=\?){0}=[^&\s]+&?)",parameterToRemove);   //this will not work for javascript, for javascript you can do following
string finalQS = Regex.Replace(queryString, regex, "");

//javascript(following is not js syntex, just want to give idea how we can able do it in js)
string regex1 = string.Format("(&{0}=[^&\s]+)",parameterToRemove);
string regex2 = string.Format("(\?{0}=[^&\s]+&?)",parameterToRemove);
string finalQS = Regex.Replace(queryString, regex1, "").Replace(queryString, regex2, "");
```

https://regexr.com/3i9vj

Comment: Unfortunately your pattern also picks up "end of" matching on the first item (e.g. change `parameterToRemove="ent"` an you'll end up with `Default.aspx?AgLanguage=2`).  If you **don't** have to support javascript, the following amendment uses positive-lookbehind to get around this: `(&{0}=[^&\s]+|(?<=\?){0}=[^&\s]+&?)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
        string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;

        int index = url.IndexOf(key);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            string post = string.Empty;

            // Find end of key's value
            int endIndex = url.IndexOf('&', index);
            if (endIndex != -1) // Last query string value?
            {
                post = url.Substring(endIndex, url.Length - endIndex);
            }

            // Decrement for ? or & character
            --index;
            ret = url.Substring(0, index) + post;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way without using Regex:

```
private string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string sURL, string sKey) {
    string sOutput = string.Empty;

    int iQuestion = sURL.IndexOf('?');
    if (iQuestion == -1) return (sURL);

    int iKey = sURL.Substring(iQuestion).IndexOf(sKey) + iQuestion;
    if (iKey == -1) return (sURL);

    int iNextAnd = sURL.Substring(iKey).IndexOf('&') + iKey + 1;

    if (iNextAnd == -1) {
        sOutput = sURL.Substring(0, iKey - 1);
    }
    else {
        sOutput = sURL.Remove(iKey, iNextAnd - iKey);
    }

    return (sOutput);
}
```

I did try this with adding another field at the end, and it works fine for that too.

Answer (score 1):

With reusing the signature from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11080157/9658902), but preserving the fragment and using `QueryHelpers` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities`.

```
public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    var newQueryString = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

    if (newQueryString.Remove(key))
    {
        var urlWithNewQuery = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(
            uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path),
            newQueryString.ToDictionary(
                queryParam => queryParam.Key,
                queryParam => queryParam.Value.ToString()))
        return $"{urlWithNewQuery}{uri.Fragment}";
    }

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the shortest way (that I *believe* produces a valid URL in all cases, assuming the URL was valid to begin with) would be to use this regex (where `getRidOf` is the variable name you are trying to remove) and the replacement is a zero-length string `""`):

```
(?<=[?&])getRidOf=[^&]*(&|$)
```

or maybe even

```
\bgetRidOf=[^&]*(&|$)
```

while possibly not the absolute *prettiest* URLs, I *think* they are all valid:

```
         INPUT                                         OUTPUT
      -----------                                   ------------
blah.com/blah.php?getRidOf=d.co&blah=foo        blah.com/blah.php?blah=foo
blah.com/blah.php?f=0&getRidOf=d.co&blah=foo    blah.com/blah.php?f=0&blah=foo
blah.com/blah.php?hello=true&getRidOf=d.co      blah.com/blah.php?hello=true&
blah.com/blah.php?getRidOf=d.co                 blah.com/blah.php?
```

and it's a simple regex replace:

```
Dim RegexObj as Regex = New Regex("(?<=[?&])getRidOf=[^&]*(&|$)")
RegexObj.Replace("source.url.com/find.htm?replace=true&getRidOf=PLEASE!!!", "")
```

...should result in the string:

```
"source.url.com/find.htm?replace=true&"
```

...which seems to be valid for an ASP.Net application, while `replace` does equal `true` (not `true&` or anything like that)

I'll try to adapt it if you have a case where it won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code before deleting your `QueryString`.

```
 PropertyInfo isreadonly = 
          typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty(
          "IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        // make collection editable
        isreadonly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, false, null);
        // remove
        this.Request.QueryString.Remove("yourKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string sURL, string sKey)
    {
        string sOutput = string.Empty;
        string sToReplace = string.Empty;

        int iFindTheKey = sURL.IndexOf(sKey);
        if (iFindTheKey == -1) return (sURL);

        int iQuestion = sURL.IndexOf('?');
        if (iQuestion == -1) return (sURL);

        string sEverythingBehindQ = sURL.Substring(iQuestion);
        List<string> everythingBehindQ = new List<string>(sEverythingBehindQ.Split('&'));
        foreach (string OneParamPair in everythingBehindQ)
        {
            int iIsKeyInThisParamPair = OneParamPair.IndexOf(sKey);
            if (iIsKeyInThisParamPair != -1)
            {
                sToReplace = "&" + OneParamPair;
            }
        }

        sOutput = sURL.Replace(sToReplace, "");
        return (sOutput);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is a bit dirty but should work in older framework

```
public String RemoveQueryString( String rawUrl  , String keyName)
{
    var currentURL_Split =  rawUrl.Split('&').ToList();
    currentURL_Split = currentURL_Split.Where(o => !o.ToLower().StartsWith(keyName.ToLower()+"=")).ToList();
    String New_RemovedKey = String.Join("&", currentURL_Split.ToArray()); 
    New_RemovedKey = New_RemovedKey.Replace("&&", "&");
    return New_RemovedKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

I'v added some extra input validation.

```
public static void TryRemoveQueryStringByKey(ref string url, string key)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ||
        Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }            

    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        // This gets all the query string key value pairs as a collection
        NameValueCollection queryCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
        string keyValue = queryCollection.Get(key);

        if (url.IndexOf("&" + key + "=" + keyValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            url = url.Replace("&" + key + "=" + keyValue, String.Empty);
            return true;
        }
        else if (url.IndexOf("?" + key + "=" + keyValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            url = url.Replace("?" + key + "=" + keyValue, String.Empty);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some unit testing examples:

```
string url1 = "http://www.gmail.com?a=1&cookie=cookieValue"
Assert.IsTrue(TryRemoveQueryStringByKey(ref url1,"cookie")); //OUTPUT: "http://www.gmail.com?a=1"

string url2 = "http://www.gmail.com?cookie=cookieValue"  
Assert.IsTrue(TryRemoveQueryStringByKey(ref url2,"cookie")); //OUTPUT: "http://www.gmail.com"

string url3 = "http://www.gmail.com?cookie="  
Assert.IsTrue(TryRemoveQueryStringByKey(ref url2,"cookie")); //OUTPUT: "http://www.gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full solution that works with >= 0 params specified, and any form of URL:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a URL in any format, return URL with specified query string param removed if it exists
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripQueryStringParam(string url, string paramToRemove)
    {
        return StripQueryStringParams(url, new List<string> {paramToRemove});
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given a URL in any format, return URL with specified query string params removed if it exists
    /// </summary>
    public static string StripQueryStringParams(string url, List<string> paramsToRemove)
    {
        if (paramsToRemove == null || !paramsToRemove.Any()) return url;

        var splitUrl = url.Split('?');
        if (splitUrl.Length == 1) return url;

        var urlFirstPart = splitUrl[0];
        var urlSecondPart = splitUrl[1];

        // Even though in most cases # isn't available to context,
        // we may be passing it in explicitly for helper urls
        var secondPartSplit = urlSecondPart.Split('#');
        var querystring = secondPartSplit[0];
        var hashUrlPart = string.Empty;
        if (secondPartSplit.Length > 1)
        {
            hashUrlPart = "#" + secondPartSplit[1];
        }
        var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
        if (!nvc.HasKeys()) return url;

        // Remove any matches
        foreach (var key in nvc.AllKeys)
        {
            if (paramsToRemove.Contains(key))
            {
                nvc.Remove(key);
            }
        }

        if (!nvc.HasKeys()) return urlFirstPart;
        return urlFirstPart + 
               "?" + string.Join("&", nvc.AllKeys.Select(c => c.ToString() + "=" + nvc[c.ToString()])) + 
               hashUrlPart;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern answer for this old question in case someone else stumbles across it like I did.

This is using the Uri class to parse the URL (can be skipped if your URL is already in a Uri object) and LINQ to filter the query string.

```
public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    var queryParts = uri.Query
        .TrimStart('?')
        .Split('&')
        .Where(item => string.CompareOrdinal(item, key) != 0);
    return uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter
        + uri.Authority
        + uri.AbsolutePath
        + "?" + string.Join("&", queryParts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this to work on a relative url, which the accepted answer doesn't. This is an adaptation of [Ash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052744/how-to-efficiently-remove-a-query-string-by-key-from-a-url#answer-25489046).

```
    public static string RemoveQueryStringParam(string url, string key)
    {
        string sOutput = string.Empty;
        string sToReplace = string.Empty;

        int iFindTheKey = url.IndexOf(key);
        if (iFindTheKey == -1) return (url);

        int iQuestion = url.IndexOf('?');
        if (iQuestion == -1) return (url);

        //loop querystring params to find the key
        string sEverythingBehindQ = url.Substring(iQuestion + 1);
        List<string> everythingBehindQ = new List<string>(sEverythingBehindQ.Split('&'));
        foreach (string OneParamPair in everythingBehindQ)
        {
            int iIsKeyInThisParamPair = OneParamPair.IndexOf(key);
            if (iIsKeyInThisParamPair != -1)
            {
                sToReplace = OneParamPair;
            }
        }

        //remove the param
        sOutput = url.Replace(sToReplace, "");

        //cleanup
        sOutput = sOutput.Replace("?&", "?");
        sOutput = sOutput.Replace("&&", "&");
        sOutput = sOutput.TrimEnd("?&".ToCharArray());

        return (sOutput);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string query, string key)
    {
        if (query == null)
            return null;
        return string.Join("&", query.Split("&").Where(s => !s.StartsWith(key)));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string[] separateURL = url.Split('?');

NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(separateURL[1]);
queryString.Remove("param_toremove");

string revisedurl = separateURL[0] + "?" + queryString.ToString();
```

Comment: Not processed case when no query