# How to remove or update part of query string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following querystring & i want to remove or update part of querystring

`?language=en-us&issue=5&pageid=18&search=hawaii&search=hawaii` // this is what i need to format

Problem is i have duplicate querystring for search key.

I tried following code but it is not working

```
public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    // this gets all the query string key value pairs as a collection
    var newQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

    // this removes the key if exists
    newQueryString.Remove(key);

    // this gets the page path from root without QueryString
    string pagePathWithoutQueryString = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

    return newQueryString.Count > 0
        ? "{0}?{1}".FormatWith(pagePathWithoutQueryString, newQueryString)
        : pagePathWithoutQueryString;
}
```

FormatWith generates error

```
string' does not contain a definition for 'FormatWith' and no extension method 'FormatWith' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

**WORKING CODE:**

```
public static string RemoveQueryStringByKey(string url, string key)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    // this gets all the query string key value pairs as a collection
    var newQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

    // this removes the key if exists
    newQueryString.Remove(key);

    // this gets the page path from root without QueryString
    string pagePathWithoutQueryString = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

    return newQueryString.Count > 0
        ? string.Format("{0}?{1}", pagePathWithoutQueryString, newQueryString)
        : pagePathWithoutQueryString;
}
```

Function Call

```
var URL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
var uri = new Uri(Helper.RemoveQueryStringByKey(URL, "search"));
```

In my actual logic i have to check if QueryString `search` is present if it is then i remove it and replace it with the new search keyword.

You can apply it as per logic, & the first example code which was not working was due to `FormatWith` which i was not able to fix so i used solution provide by `Oded` which works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `string.Format` directly. It looks like you copied the code from a code base that defines a `FormatWith` extension method which you have not copied (or haven't included the namespace it lives in).

Using `string.Format`:

```
return newQueryString.Count > 0
    ? string.Format("{0}?{1}", pagePathWithoutQueryString, newQueryString)
    : pagePathWithoutQueryString;
```

Another option, if the extension method is in the codebase, is to add a [`using` declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw.aspx) with the namespace the extension method is in.

Comment: You are right i took this code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052744/how-to-efficiently-remove-a-query-string-by-key-from-a-url i am not able to find a complete example on this

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - I had given you a different bit of code that _should_ work just fine.

Comment: I tried first code it generate error `The format of the URI could not be determined` i will try update one.Just to be more clear i dont pass all the URI, I only need to pass the query string part only as i have show in example

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker - Time to crack open the debugger. See what the values you are trying to concatenate are.

Comment: This is how my part of code problem is with URI conversion `QueryString = Request.Url.Query.ToString();
Helper.RemoveQueryStringByKey(QueryString,"search");
Helper.RemoveQueryStringByKey("?language=en-us&issue=5&pageid=18&search=hawaii", "search")`

Comment: I fixed it rather than passing QueryString i am passing now complete URL as function breaks URL into URI.Query..

Answer (score 0):

```
return newQueryString.Count > 0
        ? "{0}?{1}".FormatWith(pagePathWithoutQueryString, newQueryString)
        : pagePathWithoutQueryString;
```

> string' does not contain a definition for 'FormatWith' and no extension method 'FormatWith' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I believe that the error is self-explainatory, there's an error in your return-code.
There isn't a FormatWith in the string-object.

---

QueryStrings can also be collected with [Request.QueryString](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp), which will return a collection of keys and values.
Altering this collection and then resending it with Response.QueryString might do what you want.

Comment: How exactly is this helping the OP or answering the question?

Comment: @Oded The OP should know that the error lays at his own code and not at the code not compiling