# Clicking 2 submit buttons in the same page

Tags: c#, forms

I have a project in .Net Core with Razor Pages and I have the form bellow that contains some input fields and 2 submit buttons.

```
<form class="form-style" method="post" id="createForm">
  <div class="form-group button-position col-md4">
      <input type="submit" id="placeRequest" name="placeRequest" value="Place Request" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group button-position col-md4">
      <input type="submit" value="GetHour" asp-page-handler="Hour" class="btn btn-primary btn-style" formnovalidate />
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to be able to click the first submit button (GetHour) and then click the second one (Placer Request)

In my Razor Page model I have

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
   //code that will be executed when the Place Request button is clicked
}

 public async Task OnPostGetHour()
 {         
    ////code that will be executed when the Get Hour button is clicked
 }
```

The problem is that I am not allowed to make the 2 submits. If I only do one of them, it works but the second one does nothing

Is there any way I could make both of the submits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Razor Page with two submit buttons and return to the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791260/razor-page-with-two-submit-buttons-and-return-to-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

This is because once you click the first submit button, The page does a redirect and loads again.

This is the nature of form submission. If you want to click both the buttons. Change the button type from "submit" to "button".

Then create 2 click handlers and handle the form submitting using Ajax

```
<form class="form-style" method="post" id="createForm">
  <div class="form-group button-position col-md4">
      <input onclick="onBtn1Click()" type="button" id="placeRequest" name="placeRequest" value="Place Request" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group button-position col-md4">
      <input onclick="onBtn2Click()" type="button" value="GetHour" asp-page-handler="Hour" class="btn btn-primary btn-style" formnovalidate />
  </div>
</form>
```

Then write 2 JavaScript functions

```
function onBtn1Click()
{
  //Submit code via Ajax here
}

function onBtn2Click()
{
  //Submit code via Ajax here
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the first button will submit some data that I need to use in my C# code (in the Razor Page Model). Does Ajax allow to send the data to the model?

Comment: You can easily achieve it using partial view binding